# sending and receiving information from https

Tags: javascript, ajax, https

Sorry if this sounds stupid but I really am over my head here. At work I have made a website and another guy at my work has made a webserver.  My website is https, and I have found I can reach my website by typing 
"https://myurl
or
http://myurl

In my website I make a call to the webserver that looks like this...

```
$.ajax({
 crossDomain:true,
 contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
 type:"POST",
 url: 'http://urlOfWebserver/'+data.method,
 dataType:"jsonp",
 data: data.data,
 success: function (data){}
```

When i am at my site with http everything works, but when I am on my site with the https prefix i get the following error

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://myurl' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://urlOfWebserver/MQueryString. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Can this issue be fixed from my website or does it need to be fixed on the webserver?

Comment: Use a protocol-relative url in the form `"//urlOfWebserver/"` which will use https on pages served over https thus avoiding the mixed content warning.

Comment: I just tried that it still works when my website is http
But when i put my website on https it gives me this new error instead of the old one
"net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Comment: I think that error messages are quite descriptive: ```url: 'http://urlOfWebserver/'``` - check if you can access ```urlOfWebserver``` via ```https```... If yes: that should work. If no: try making it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for documentation about CORS can help you
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS